# MVC MultiSelectList Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I use ASP.NET MVC .. When i post my form it's raise cast error when my model validate. How can fixed my view model or another validation way?

"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."
Thank you..

```
//my view model
public class ProdGroupViewModel
{
    //I've to fixed here or another way?
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rooms { get; set; }
}


//controller
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    return View(new ProdGroupViewModel
            {
                Rooms = new MultiSelectList(_roomService.GetAll(), "RoomId", "RoomName"),
            });

}

//in my view
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Oda</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Rooms, (MultiSelectList)Model.Rooms, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to post to the same property that holds your select list. The posted result of a selections in a listbox will be a comma-delimited string of the selected option values, which the modelbinder would be incapable of binding to a property of type `MultiSelectList`.

You need an additional model property to hold the posted value like:

```
public List<int> SelectedRoomIds { get; set; }
```

And then in your view:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoomIds, Model.Rooms, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

*Also, you don't need to cast `Model.Rooms`, since it's already strongly-typed.*